# Build DateTime from string value based on the current system culture

Tags: c#, .net

What I need is to use string variables to build DateTime based on the current system culture.

[Some example says to do it manually](http://www.csharp-examples.net/string-format-datetime/)

```
// date separator in german culture is "." (so "/" changes to ".")
String.Format("{0:d/M/yyyy HH:mm:ss}", dt); // "9/3/2008 16:05:07" - english (en-US)
String.Format("{0:d/M/yyyy HH:mm:ss}", dt); // "9.3.2008 16:05:07" - german (de-DE)
```

But is there a way to do it automatically?

Is this code correct?

```
DateTime dateValue;
CultureInfo culture = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;
DateTimeStyles styles = DateTimeStyles.None;
string strDateTime = string.Format("{0}/{1}/{2} {3}:{4}:{5}", systemTime.month, systemTime.day, systemTime.year, systemTime.hour, systemTime.minute, systemTime.second);
DateTime.TryParse(strDateTime, culture, styles, out dateValue);
```

---

Just for someone who needs it I will put all methods here:

```
 DateTime dateValue;

        // Method 1
        //CultureInfo culture = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;
        //DateTimeStyles styles = DateTimeStyles.None;
        //string strDateTime = string.Format("{0}/{1}/{2} {3}:{4}:{5}", systemTime.month, systemTime.day, systemTime.year, systemTime.hour, systemTime.minute, systemTime.second);
        //DateTime.TryParse(strDateTime, culture, styles, out dateValue);

        // Method 2
        //DateTime d = new DateTime(systemTime.year, systemTime.month, systemTime.day, systemTime.hour, systemTime.minute, systemTime.second);
        //dateValue = DateTime.Parse(d.ToString("G"));

        // Method 3 http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ch92fbc1.aspx The string s is parsed using formatting information in the current DateTimeFormatInfo object, which is supplied implicitly by the current thread culture.
        DateTime d = new DateTime(systemTime.year, systemTime.month, systemTime.day, systemTime.hour, systemTime.minute, systemTime.second);
        DateTime.TryParse(d.ToString(), out dateValue);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `DateTime.TryParse(string, out DateTime result)` it automatically uses the current culture. See the Remarks section here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ch92fbc1.aspx

Answer (score 2):

You can use the current culture automatically by passing [the `"G"` format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx) to `ToString`:

```
string result = dt.ToString("G"); // 9/3/2008 4:05:07 PM for en-US
```

[Here's a demo.](http://ideone.com/6LYLp)